# Mainframe (Reflection Sessions) - Determining cursor position from within Excel

Tags: excel, function, screen-scraping, mainframe

When controlling mainframe from Excel there are several functions one can use to navigate and scrape data. Some of these functions include, .GetString(x, y), .Putstring(x, y) and .MoveTo(x, y), just to name a few. (x denotes row #, y denotes column #, think of these like coordinates)

I have looked extensively online; (IBM redbooks, whitepapers, google, the stack, reflection api/vba manauls, tek-tips, websites strictly devoted to mainframe, etc)

One function I have been unable to find; a function that returns the cursor's current position within Mainframe's window.

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: Which Terminal emulator are you using ???; there may be differences between the emulators

Comment: OP is using Reflection, which appears to be a package that includes TN3270 methods. He's posted another question in the past week about Reflection. Based on a comment the OP made in the other thread, it seems like the Internet is rather lacking in documentation on the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to obtain cursor position by running the following code in reflection's VBE

```
Sub getCoordinates()

Dim ibmCurrentTerminal As IbmTerminal
Dim ibmCurrentScreen As IbmScreen
Dim returnValue As Integer
Set ibmCurrentTerminal = ThisFrame.SelectedView.control
Set ibmCurrentScreen = ibmCurrentTerminal.Screen
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
ibmCurrentTerminal.Productivity.ScreenHistory.ClearAllScreens
ibmCurrentTerminal.Productivity.RecentTyping.ClearAllItems

Dim CursorColumn As Integer
Dim valueColumn As Integer
Dim CursorRow As Integer
Dim valueRow As Integer

ibmCurrentScreen.CursorColumn = valueColumn
ibmCurrentScreen.CursorRow = valueRow
valueColumn = ibmCurrentScreen.CursorColumn
valueRow = ibmCurrentScreen.CursorRow

MsgBox "(" & valueRow & ", " & valueColumn & ")"

End Sub
```

This works if you want to retrieve cursor position, albeit via msgbox